# Text sizing issues when using small scale text mesh in Unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

When using textmesh to add a label to my prefab gameObject in Unity, the text appears really squashed and not filling the space properly and I can't seem to figure out how to make it appear normal. I had the same issue using plain text.
Even if i make the canvas way bigger than I want it just to test, the text is all squashed and distorted

I am using a canvas and my scaling is quite small

[image: image of using best fit]

[image: image using a font size (appears very squashed)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*:
Try to add a `CanvasScaler` component to your container `Canvas` gameObject (add it only if it is not there yet).

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

It has some properties but the most important is the `Reference Pixels Per Unit` set it to a higher, or a *much* higher number.

If your container `Canvas` has its `Render Mode` in *Screen Space - Overlay*, then your text will look little "stretched" - as your picture shows it. If you modify the scale mode to anything else, then this will be alright.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I think the issue might be that my prefab object is really small? - if I put the canvas scalar to scale with screen size, then I can't make the text box small enough wrt the prefab object

Comment: I modified my answer a little, check if it helps